# Can't display the elements of linked list properly after inserting the element to head

Tags: python, linked-list

I have a linked list, in which each node holds the circle's data (color, radius). I have a class 'Shape' which has

(i) **init** : To initialize the circle_list.

(ii) get_circle_list(): which returns the circle_list

(iii) insert_circle(new_circle) : which inserts the new node at the head position of the circle_list.

The function **init** and insert_circle(new_circle) work perfectly. But when I try to use the get_circle_list(), it returns the old circle_list and not the updated one.

For instance, the new node I want to insert in the head position is ("Blue", 6), then the insert_circle(new_circle) inserts it correctly at the head position. But when I try to print shape.get_circle_list().display(), the same old circle_list is printed.

PS: Please don't confuse this code for circular linked list, which it isn't. This is a linked list which has nodes representing a circle's features and the list is referred to with the name circle_list.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.__data=data
        self.__next=None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.__data

    def set_data(self,data):
        self.__data=data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.__next

    def set_next(self,next_node):
        self.__next=next_node


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__head=None
        self.__tail=None

    def get_head(self):
        return self.__head

    def get_tail(self):
        return self.__tail


    def add(self,data):
        new_node=Node(data)
        if(self.__head is None):
            self.__head=self.__tail=new_node
        else:
            self.__tail.set_next(new_node)
            self.__tail=new_node

    def insert(self,data,data_before):
        new_node=Node(data)
        if(data_before==None):
            new_node.set_next(self.__head)
            self.__head=new_node
            if(new_node.get_next()==None):
                self.__tail=new_node

        else:
            node_before=self.find_node(data_before)
            if(node_before is not None):
                new_node.set_next(node_before.get_next())
                node_before.set_next(new_node)
                if(new_node.get_next() is None):
                    self.__tail=new_node
            else:
                print(data_before,"is not present in the Linked list")

    def display(self):
        temp=self.__head
        while(temp is not None):
            print(temp.get_data())
            temp=temp.get_next()

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, color,radius):
        self.__color=color
        self.__radius=radius

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.__color+" "+str(self.__radius))

    def get_color(self):
        return self.__color

    def get_radius(self):
        return self.__radius


class Shape:
    def __init__(self,circle_list):
        self.__circle_list=circle_list
    #Here is where the problem occurs
    def get_circle_list(self):
        return self.__circle_list
    def insert_circle(self,new_circle):
        newNode=Node(new_circle)
        newNode.set_next(self.__circle_list.get_head())
        self.__circle_list.__head=newNode


circle1=Circle("Red",4)
circle2=Circle("Green",5)
circle3=Circle("Purple",3.5)
new_circle=Circle("Blue",6)

circle_list=LinkedList()
circle_list.add(circle1)
circle_list.add(circle2)
circle_list.add(circle3)

shape=Shape(circle_list)
shape.insert_circle(new_circle)
#prints the same old circle_list here
shape.get_circle_list().display()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using attribute names that start with two underscores, such as `__head` and `__circle_list`, and Python has special rules for such names.

Use only one underscore, or none, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The python interpreter replaces the name of class members starting with `__` (double underscore) to _classname__membername as a way to ensure that this name will not overlap with a similar name in another class.

In your case the the `__head` attribute is interpreted as `_LinkedList__head`.

When you call the `insert_circle` method `self.__circle_list.__head = newNode` is creating a new `__head` attribute, not reassigning `_LinkedList__head`.

You could add a `set_head` method to your `LinkedList`

```
def set_head(self,new_head):
        self.__head=new_head
```

Then call it in the `insert_circle` method.

```
def insert_circle(self,new_circle):
        newNode=Node(new_circle)
        newNode.set_next(self.__circle_list.get_head())
        self.__circle_list.set_head(newNode)
```

You can also access the _LinkedList__head attribute directly

```
def insert_circle(self,new_circle):
        newNode=Node(new_circle)
        newNode.set_next(self.__circle_list.get_head())
        self.__circle_list._LinkedList__head=newNode
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to insert the data in the head position,

```
def insert_circle(self,new_circle):
    self.__circle_list.insert(new_circle,None)
```

To display the list:

```
def get_circle_list(self):
    return self.__circle_list
```

Add the above functions to your code.